# Can not run sample test Koin

Tags: koin

I want to run sample test from this site https://insert-koin.io/docs/2.0/getting-started/junit-test/

```
class HelloAppTest : AutoCloseKoinTest() {

val model by inject<HelloMessageData>()
val service by inject<HelloService>()

@Before
fun before() {
    startKoin {
        modules(helloModule)
    }
}

@Test
fun tesKoinComponents() {
    val helloApp = HelloApplication()
    helloApp.sayHello()

    assertEquals(service, helloApp.helloService)
    assertEquals("Hey, ${model.message}", service.hello())
}
}
```

But it gives following error :

```
 No tests found for given includes: [HelloAppTest] 
 (filter.includeTestsMatching)
```

My gradle file is this :

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile
buildscript {

dependencies {
    classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.31")
   }
}

plugins {
 kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.21" // duplicate for variable
}

group = "adf"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
 jcenter()
}

dependencies {
 implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))

implementation("org.koin:koin-core:2.0.0-rc-1")
testCompile("org.koin:koin-test:2.0.0-rc-1")

}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
 kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
  useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

How to handle it? Anybody, please help me

And this is just for stackoverflow.com:

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Answer (score 0):

you need to include following imports:

```
testImplementation "junit:junit:4.12"
```

Comment: If it helped you, mark it as correct. Otherwise let me know.